# SoapUI dataSource illegal character in authority

Tags: datasource, soapui

I am trying to use an external dataSource in SoapUI to send some basic GET http requests to a number of nodes, and i get "Illegal character in authority at index 7".

What i have setup.

1x dataSource (external file > excel):
The nodes setup appears to be correct (its called "nodes") > column required is called "node".
Getting the rows from the datafile from the dataSource options appear to be working correctly.

1x HTTP request
GET request, URL is: http://${nodes#node}:2040/api/doSometimes

I know i need to add the loop at the end, however the HTTP request isn't working with the first node yet, so i'll do the loop once the request works.

The error i get when trying to run the HTTP request:
Sun Aug 10 11:20:18 IDT 2014:ERROR:An error occurred [Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX /api/doSomething], see error log for details (where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the first ADDRESS from the nodes#node file).  -- Also notice its missing the port.

The error log sais: Sun Aug 10 11:29:25 IDT 2014:ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException

Clarification: we do not have a WSDL available, however the service does reply to different queries. /api/sendID WILL return the ID. I want to get all IDS from all NODES in the file.

Any ideas what i can do to mend this ?

Answer (score 0):

Used a preset REST request which included the required parameters. Used standard testsuite > added the request port directly in the datasource #node which appeared to be causing the issue.